# Present bitmap while entry point activity is loading?

Tags: android

My app takes about 3 seconds to load (yes lots of room for improvement there). Before the user is presented with my entry activity, I get an empty white screen. Is it possible to throw a bitmap there so it doesn't look so ghastly? I think I remember reading somewhere that you can present something here through the use of styles while the actual application is still being started up,

Thanks

Comment: try to add a splash screen it will display till ur app loads

Answer (score 0):

I would simply show a splash screen with an ImageView.

Something like this in `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(mySplashImageView);
asyncTaskExecutor.runInBackground(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // something that takes a long time to finish
        ..... CODE ....
        // when the heavy code above finished, use a handler or something to notify your UI thread to swap its main content view.
    }
});
```

On receiving a notification that the heavy code finished, simply *reset* the main content view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainScreen);
```